# Geoserver Custom Map on Traccar (XYZ Map Tiles) version 5.2

Tags: gis, geoserver, xyz, traccar

How do I get the Geoserver XYZ map tiles weblink to use in Traccar?

Here is a previous post this exact question was asked in but I am unable to get the correct link to work in Traccar (asked by @Rezky S):

I want to generate map from geoserver to use as map for Traccar. For the map test, for example, OSM has no problems and appears normal as shown below. Traccar With OSM

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04FkX.png)
However, when I create a layer map with the geoserver and then I try to display it on Traccar, the map that appears appears repeatedly and is not as full as the map view. Traccar With Geoserver
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoADA.png)

Did I miss something or did I make a mistake? Please can anyone help me resolve this ?

If there is something that is still lacking from my explanation or something is still not clear, please let me know, I will be happy to explain the problem.

And here are the comments:
how did you add the map? WMTS, TMS, XYZ? what URL did you use? – Ian Turton May 29 at 11:15

Thanks for clarifying the question, I've looked into it and have found a solution. Previously I used a code gridset (4326) with dimensions of 2x1, so I used a code gridset (900913) with dimensions of 1x1. I also found the use of "flipY=true" so that the position of the map that is clipped from top to bottom is correct. so that the previous url : 'localhost:8090/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/…{z}/{x}/{y}.png?flipY=true' Become : 'localhost:8090/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/…{z}/{x}/{y}.png?flipY=true' And it works. –
Rezky S Jun 7 at 3:43

you should make that an answer and then accept it to help future users – Ian Turton Jun 7 at 7:50

Where do I get the following link in Geoserver or how do I create it: 'localhost:8090/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/…{z}/{x}/{y}.png?flipY=true'

Firstly, I am not sure where to get the XYZ map tiles link for my map on Geoserver.
Under Layer Preview in Geoserver I have found the wms link:
http://localhost:8888/geoserver/ramm-live-data/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=ramm-live-data%3ABinLift&bbox=-180.0%2C-90.0%2C180.0%2C90.0&width=768&height=384&srs=EPSG%3A4326&format=image%2Fpng

And under Tile Layers Preview I have found the png link:
http://172.16.0.131:8888/geoserver/gwc/demo/ramm-live-data:BinLift?gridSet=EPSG:4326&format=image/png

Both of these links are not working and I have tried restructuring them as shown in previous forums.

Furthermore, I have discovered a 'main.6cd3a572.js.map' file that has the links to each of the maps shows on the Traccar website. However, this file is very difficult to read as there are no structure to the file code.